# several minimum cut on a graph with limited group size

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm working on graphs each with 140 nodes and edges of positive integer weight. the sum of the weights is 420, so there are at most 420 edges on each graph. some of the graphs are not fully connected.

the rule of cutting the graph is that each group must have 4 nodes, meaning 35 groups. the objective is to minimize the summed weight of the cut edges (edges that connect nodes of different groups)

can somebody help me with some algorithm suggestions? (I know that splitting the graph in two and optimizing the split cut each time can give a nice solution, but I'm looking for the strictly optimal solution)

as you might have guessed, the background of this problem is dorm assigning, each student saying who the three people they would like to be in the same dorm with, and the teachers finding the strictly optimal solution based on student satisfaction. Each dorm must house 4 students.

Comment: Since 420 = 3x140, am I right in guessing that the weights are all 1 or 2: 1 if just one student in the pair requests the other, and 2 if both do?

Comment: yeah, basically the weight of a edge between two students is 1 if one wants to be in the same room as the other, and 2 if they both want to be in the same room, 0 if otherwise. there are no other possibilities, thanks for pointing this out though, I forgot to put it in the question.

Comment: Noodling on a starting point; may write this up later: Let G' be the the graph limited to wt-2 edges. Find all K4s in G'; each of these is a room. Next, Find all K3s in G' (no node is in more than 1), and find the maximal matching between these and remaining nodes using edges & weights from G (not G'). 

That's all I have for now.

Comment: I think this'd be somehow from far, but related to the stable matching problem. In that, with Lloyd-Shapley you try to find the optimal solution by swapping pairs (well, chains actually) of people around until you can't improve. The problem is quite different, there you have 2 sets of people and everyone has a list of preferences; but there are variations to the problem in research that could be relevant. You could e.g. define an edge between every pair of students, with preference 1 for the initial <420 edges and 2 for others. You match pairs of people in the original task, for you its quads.

Comment: You could maybe think of an algorithm: You partition nodes into 35 groups arbitrarily. Look for pairs of nodes from different groups where if you swap them, they'll lower the weight sum.
This would converge and give a minimum but I'm not sure if it would be a global minimum (don't know if there could be a solution with smaller weight sum that you could only reach by at least 1 swap that temporarily increase the sum). If yes, then great, this should do the trick, if not then still you can find something similar, bit more complex but still fast for your case (only 4 node components) I believe

Comment: I think the problem will be that there are usually many optimal solutions, not just one. A solution that grants a student all his wishes and another one none of them could have the same score as one that grants both students half of their wishes. So modelling as directed graph with possibly 2 edges between node also makes sense. Plus additional scoring rules that account for the even distribution of granted wishes. You could also give first choice weight of 3, 2nd 2 and 3rd 1 to have a clearer picture and less optimal solutions.

Comment: If modelled as directed graph you can calculate the score for each node as the sum of the weights of its outgoing edges after cutting, then sum all node scores and take the negative or reciprocal because you want to minimize the score. The score for the cutting stays the same, there are just more edges.